# Remove duplicates python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have data like this:

```
d = {'col1': ['1-2-3', '2-2-3'], 'col2': ['1-2-2-3', '4-4-4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    col1    col2
0   1-2-3   1-2-2-3
1   2-2-3   4-4-4
```

I need to remove the duplicates and preserve the order to achieve this:

```
    col1    col2
0   1-2-3   1-2-3
1   2-3     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)...

if order is important use `split` with `dict.fromkeys` for remove duplicates, last join back:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: '-'.join(dict.fromkeys(x.split('-')).keys()))
print (df)
    col1   col2
0  1-2-3  1-2-3
1    2-3      4
```

if order is not important use `set`s:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: '-'.join(set(x.split('-'))))
print (df)
    col1   col2
0  3-2-1  3-2-1
1    3-2      4
```

Answer (score 1):

drop_duplicates is the generic API you can use.
But in this special case, you can create a temporary column, put all of the numbers as a list.
And then again convert that in the non-duplicated string

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('-'), axis=1) 
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join((list(dict.fromkeys(x)))) )
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join((list(dict.fromkeys(x)))) )
df
```